# Is the Book of Mormon considered to be another Gospel? (LDS perspective)

Tags: bible, lds, gospels, book-of-mormon

Is the Book of Mormon considered to be another Gospel? 
Paul tells us not to accept any other gospels apart from the one he has preached. Is the Book of Mormon considered to be another gospel? If so, why?

Inviting Mormon perspectives.

> 6 I marvel that you are turning away so soon from Him who called you
>   in the grace of Christ, to a different gospel, 7 which is not another;
>   but there are some who trouble you and want to pervert the gospel of
>   Christ. 8 But even if we, or an angel from heaven, preach any other
>   gospel to you than what we have preached to you, let him be accursed.
>   9 As we have said before, so now I say again, if anyone preaches any
>   other gospel to you than what you have received, let him be accursed.
>
> **Galatians 1:6-9**

Comment: Have you taken a look at what is considered "canon" among major Protestant denominations and Catholics?   [Here is a related question with some answers](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/45240/24204).  Given that Catholics and Protestants don't agree on Canon and have not for about 500 years, adding their views to this question might be out of scope.   I suggest that you scope this question for the Church of Jesus Christ of the Latter Day Saints.

Comment: Questions asking the teachings of more  than one denomination are typically considered too broad.  If you restrict this question to Mormon teachings, there is a good chance it will be reopened.

Comment: The question as currently worded seems odd and borderline unclear; when most Christians speak of "another gospel" they mean a *false* gospel, so *of course* Mormons don't believe their holy book is "another gospel" in that sense. It seems like the question (now that it's restricted to LDS views) should really be something like "Do Mormons believe Paul taught the true Gospel?" or "In what respects (if any) do LDS teachers claim that their Gospel differs from Paul's?" or "What is the Gospel according to the LDS Church?" Change it to something in that vein and I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: Actually, noticing now that pretty good answers exist to the current question, I'll vote to reopen. I'll leave my previous comment though as a suggestion for a future question or questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, according to the subtitle to The Book of Mormon, it is "Another Testament of Jesus Christ", not another gospel.

Quoting from [the title page](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/bofm-title?lang=eng) of The Book of Mormon (emphasis mine):

> Which is **to show unto the remnant of the house of Israel what great things the Lord hath done** for their fathers; and **that they may know the covenants of the Lord**, that they are not cast off forever—And also to the convincing of the Jew and Gentile that Jesus is the Christ, the Eternal God, manifesting himself unto all nations

From the [Introduction](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/introduction?lang=eng):

> It is a record of God’s dealings with ancient inhabitants of the Americas and contains the fulness of the everlasting gospel.

It contains the fulness of *the* everlasting gospel, not a new gospel. Continued (emphasis mine):

> The record is now published in many languages **as a new and additional witness that Jesus Christ is the Son of the living God** and that all who will come unto Him and obey the laws and ordinances of His gospel may be saved.

One of the commenters asked what "Testament" means. From this, we see it means a witness, like a testimony.

When the record describes Christ visiting the Americas, He [teaches basically the same Sermon on the Mount that He taught by the Sea of Galilee](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/3-ne/12?lang=eng). And [Jesus speaks of the people back in Jerusalem](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/3-ne/15?lang=eng) and why He came here to teach them the same gospel in the Americas, too.

It very much is the same gospel. Missionaries of the LDS Church preach by the Bible and Book of Mormon because the Book of Mormon does not replace the Bible; rather, they testify of each other and of the same Lord Jesus Christ.

Comment: In regular Biblical language, 'Testament' means Covenant. In other words the 'New Testament' is a New Covenant, replacing the Old Covenant of Judaism. Does it mean Testament in this sense?

Comment: Not really. It means testimony, or witness.

Comment: I think an argument can be made that the Book of Mormon is another testament in the sense of covenant. In Reformed covenant theology we don’t consider the old (Mosaic) and new (Christ) covenants to be separate covenants strictly speaking, but different administrations of a single covenant of grace. The title page of the Book of Mormon does state that its purpose is to witness of Christ, but it also says it is written “that [Israel] may know the covenants of the Lord.” [1/2]

Comment: The Book of Mormon describes a covenant that was made with Joseph (son of Jacob/Israel) which passed to Joseph's descendants, the families of Lehi and Nephi. The fulfillment of this covenant involved the migration of Lehi’s family to their own promised land, the new world. (Eventually the people were also introduced to the same new (Christ) covenant that the people in the old world received.) So the Covenant of Joseph could be the other “testament” (another administration of the same covenant of grace) referred to in the subtitle of the Book of Mormon. [2/2]

Answer (score 7):

Your interpretation of Paul's warning is anachronistic. At Paul's time there was no Bible, he wasn't referring to the four gospels according to Mathew, Mark, Luke, and John. He was referring to the "good news" that the saviour had come, and that through him we could be redeemed from sin. The Book of Mormon is not a different gospel. **It is the *same* gospel** (the same good news) that Paul and all the other apostles taught–that Christ is our Saviour, and by following him we can receive salvation from our sins.

Answer (score 2):

No. Not how most would define it. The Mormon church publicly states the book is  "Another Testament of Jesus Christ." Or sometimes referred to as another witness of Jesus Christ. It is written by men of God, prophets, just like the Bible.

The Bible says "In the mouth of two or three witnesses shall every word be established" 2 Corinthians 13:1.

It is so strange to think that God speaks to many people. Many prophets. And those prophets may record the words of the Lord as well.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Unfortunately, the question itself is not specific enough, and will likely be closed. Meanwhile, for some tips on writing good answers here, please see: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/20394) And for more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Answer (score 1):

Proverbs 30:6 Add thou not unto his words, lest he reprove thee, and thou be found a liar.

The Bible is totally sufficient for all righteousness, wisdom, and truth (II Tim 3:16-17; II Pet 1:19-21). There is no need for further revelation, human rationalization, or religious tradition (I Tim 6:3-5,20-21).

Adding your thoughts to His inspired words is only arrogance and folly (Deut 4:2; 12:32; Matt 28:20). Since He has magnified His word above all His name, He will not take any profane additions lightly (Ps 138:2). He will judge men severely for adding their lying thoughts to His pure words (Pr 30:5; Re 22:18).

There are no better ideas. Reject the thought! All thoughts of man are vain (I Cor 1:19-20; 3:19-20). All of them! Thoughts of modern man are even more foolish and profitless. God has spoken, and that settles every issue, controversy, and question (Ps 119:128; Is 30:8). Let God be true, but every man a liar (Rom 3:4). Progress in science or other fields of learning is the prosperity of fools (Pr 1:32; Deut 32:15; Ps 69:22; 92:7; I Tim 6:20-21). It is God’s blinding judgment on men as they sink deeper into a moral cesspool of ignorance and depravity.

But Bible corrupters have been around for a long time (II Cor 2:17). They have added to and taken away from the Scriptures from the beginning, when Satan began his conquest of the human family by altering the words of God to Eve (Gen 3:1-6). And they are worse today than ever, as Paul warned Timothy (I Tim 4:1-3; II Tim 3:13). Through extended education and the information explosion, human learning is expanding geometrically, but without God’s truth (II Tim 3:6-7).

Consider a few additions that God has and will reprove as lies. The Mother Church adds the confused and contradictory opinions of the so-called church fathers. The Seventh Day Adventists add the visions of Ellen Harmon. The Mormons add the plagiarized fantasies of Joseph Smith - **adding their own books**, the ***Book of Mormon*** (Another Testament), Pearl of Great Price, Doctrines & Covenants to the King James Version.  Which book are YOU going to believe for salvation?

Joseph Smith received from God first through an angel, then a book inscribed on golden plates.

Gal 1 6 I marvel that ye are so soon removed from him that called you into the grace of Christ unto another gospel: 7 Which is not another; but there be some that trouble you, and would pervert the gospel of Christ. 8 But though we (even PAUL), or an angel from heaven, preach any other gospel unto you than that which we have preached unto you, let him be accursed. 9 As we said before, so say I now again, If any man preach any other gospel unto you than that ye have received, let him be accursed
Mormon, what part of this don’t you understand? Did the lightbulb go off?